# Hide the url parameters using mod_rewrite function in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website that pass the parameter like: www.abc.com/write.php?id=101&q=ok using $_GET method.Is it possible to hide all the parameters passed after write.php using apache mod_rewrite function? I want the url like: www.abc.com/write.php only..Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste relevant code?

Comment: Not a good idea though, but if you want you can change it with javascript, after rendering the page using **pushState**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You need to create an **.htaccess** file with the following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^write\.php$ write.php?id=101&q=ok [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will ensure that all the incoming requests to *write.php* are translated to *write.php?id=101&q=ok*.